# Make decision on GCC compiler output [if warning.. do this] [if error.. do this]

Tags: bash, gcc, compiler-construction, makefile, warnings

**How can I individually handle errors and warnings outputed by the GCC compiler?**
For example, if a program is compiled,
how would I get all the errors to go to "error.txt"
and all of the warnings to go to "warnings.txt"
I assume there is an easy solution for this, but let me provide more detail:

I've written a GNU makefile to compile with GCC and the makefile rules are performed by bash.
I would like this branching decision to take place in the rule of my makefile.
So maybe something like this for example:

```
if (PROGRAM_HAS_NO_ERRORS_OR_WARNINGS); then\  
    echo "Everything went well";\  
else\  
    if (PROGRAM_HAS_WARNINGS); then\  
        echo "HERE ARE THE WARNINGS: " $(PROGRAM_WARNINGS);\  
    fi;\
    if (PROGRAM_HAS_ERRORS); then\  
        echo "HERE ARE THE ERRORS: " $(PROGRAM_ERRORS);\  
    fi;\
fi;
```

I was under the impression that the warnings were cout..  and errors were cerr..
and that cout corresponded to 1 and cerr corresponded to 2.
However, when I run something like this:

```
$(COMPILE) 1>warnings.txt 2>errors.txt
```

everything goes to errors.txt

So I definitely don't want to send it to a file and then parse through it if there is an easier way.

---

**some other notes that may not be important:**

```
if ($(COMPILE)); then\
```

/\ even if there are warnings, it will evaluate to true... UNLESS
I provide the flag "-Werror" which just makes the warnings errors and gcc refuses to compile the program

Comment: `./script.sh > log_file 2> err_file` this doesn't work for you?

Comment: `cout` and `cerr` are the names given by C++ to the iostream objects that write to standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr).

Comment: Errors and warnings both go to stderr. Would you be willing to filter them with, say, sed?

Comment: @Beta
AH! If thats the case, I suppose it's my best option! I will parse it by checking for the word "warning" immediately following the file and line number. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lends itself to a named pipe and a case statement similar to this:

```
mkfifo errors.txt

while read LINE; do
  case "$LINE" in
    *[Ee]rror*)error_function $LINE;;
    *[Ww]arning*)warning_function $LINE;;
    *)echo GENERAL ERROR MSG : $LINE;;
  esac
done <errors.txt &

make 2> errors.txt &
```